# How to get a list of all indexes in python-elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How would I get a list of the names of an index in Python? Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> es=e.es
>>> es
<Elasticsearch([{'host': '14555f777d8097.us-east-1.aws.found.io', 'port': 9200}])>
>>> es.indices
<elasticsearch.client.indices.IndicesClient object at 0x10de86790>
# how to get a list of all indexes in this cluster?
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`get_aliases()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_aliases) method? According to [this example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#_examples_2), you should be able to use a wildcard `*` to get all indexes.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This question comes up when searching for information on retrieving `aliases` using the `python-elasticsearch` library. The accepted answer says to use `get_aliases` but that method has been removed (as of 2017). To get `aliases`, you can use the following:

```
 es.indices.get_alias("*")
```

**UPDATE**

The latest usage should be with a keyword arg:

```
es.indices.get_alias(index="*")
```

Comment: This now raises a DeprecationWarning (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1698). I believe that the correct way to use it is now: ` es.indices.get_alias(index="*")`.

Answer (score 52):

To get a list of all the indexes in a cluster, use a wildcard.

This works with elasticsearch-py.

```
# Python 2
for index in es.indices.get('*'):
  print index

# Python 3
for index in es.indices.get('*'):
  print(index)
```

Comment: raise TypeError(
TypeError: Positional arguments can't be used with Elasticsearch API methods. Instead only use keyword arguments.

Answer (score 42):

Here is one way to do it with the [`get_alias()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=indicesclient#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_alias) method:

```
>>> indices=es.indices.get_alias().keys()
>>> sorted(indices)
[u'avails', u'hey', u'kibana-int']
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work?
`res = es.search()`
`sorted(set(res["hits"]["hits"][k]["_index"] for k in xrange(len(res["hits"]["hits"]))))`

Comment: Looks like this method has been removed from recent versions of python-elasticsearch (2017).

Comment: This answer is not valid for es5.x onwards

Comment: it is actually `get_alias` not `get_aliases()` 
ex: `es_client.indices.get_alias().keys()` api changed probably since then

Comment: I personally find `indices_dict = es.indices.get_alias()` just easier to interpret on the fly

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Cat API:`es.cat.indices(h='index', s='index').split()`

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use [pyelasticsearch module](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) they have support for the `GET _mapping` command, which produces the schema of the cluster. This will allow you to see the indices, and drill into each index to see doc_types, and their fields, etc. Here's an example:

```
import pyelasticsearch as pyes
es = pyes.ElasticSearch(["http://hostname0:9200", "http://hostname1:9200"]) ## don't accidentally type Elasticsearch, the class from the other two modules
schema = es.get_mapping() ## python dict with the map of the cluster
```

To get just the list of indices,

```
indices_full_list = schema.keys()
just_indices = [index for index in indices_full_list if not index.startswith(".")] ## remove the objects created by marvel, e.g. ".marvel-date"
```

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748920/equivalent-of-get-mapping-marvel-sense-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I use curl to call the stats API and get information about the indices. Then I parse the JSON object that is returned to find the index names.

```
curl localhost:9200/_stats
```

In Python you can call curl using the requests library. I don't know of a way to do this using the Elasticsearch or Elasticsearch-DSL Python library.

Comment: For some reason `*/_stats` wasn't working for me, but `*/_mapping` did work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get _mapping to get list of all indexes by doing something like that.

```
requests.get(full_elastic_url + "/_mapping")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'alias name' and not 'index name', here the perfect solution:

```py
response = es.indices.get(indexname)
alias_names = list(response[indexname]['aliases'].keys())
```

In `alias_names` we get list of alias names on a particular index.

Answer (score 1):

`_cat` API seems the right way to do this, since the `_aliases` way of doing will soon be removed by elasticsearch since it exposes the system indices.

```
indices = es.cat.indices(h='index', s='index').split()
```

It did the job for me.