# Equivalent of `GET _mapping` marvel/sense in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, get, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to explore an elasticsearch cluster using python, and I'm new to elasticsearch. If I use Marvel/Sense, I can see the cluster's schema using  `GET _mapping`. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Python? If so I can see the "schema" of the cluster!

More generally, I'd like to discover programmatically all the indicies, each indices' doc_types, classify the doc_types' fields (are they text strings, ints, floats, what range to the numeric ones take, ..) basically learn the schema and basic statistics of each field. If there is a better way than `GET _mapping` to start this project, I'm all ears.

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928506/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-indexes-in-python-elasticsearch/31929047#31929047), where they are looking for a list of indices using Python, but is more general.

Comment: @Ahmed posted another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31929047/2487607)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with pyelasticsearch. [This](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=mapping#pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearch.get_mapping) is how you can do `GET _mapping`
in python.

From the Docs

> get_mapping(index=None, doc_type=None) [[source]](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/pyelasticsearch/client/#ElasticSearch.get_mapping)
>
> Fetch the mapping definition for a specific index and type.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - index – An index or iterable thereof
> - doc_type – A document type or iterable thereof
>
> Omit both arguments to get mappings for all types and indexes.

Explore [API](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/) to learn more

Comment: [It's a good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: thank you @ChintanShah25. I wasn't aware of pyelasticsearch. So to my knowledge there are three python modules for elasticsarch, (1) pyelasticsearch (the first one), elasticsearch (the official one), and elasticsearch-dsl (higher level). Are there more python tools it would be worth familiarizing myself with?

Comment: _pyelasticsearch_ was written before ES released [official client](https://www.elastic.co/blog/unleash-the-clients-ruby-python-php-perl?q=client%20python#python) for python. They did borrow the code from pyelasticsearch. on a side note official client seems to have more options to [get_mapping](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=mapping#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_mapping)

Comment: Thanks. I think that's a bit more specific than what you suggested above. It is a method for an index class, not for the whole cluster as I understand it.